# How to sketch this polar curve with range $0\le\theta\lt2\pi$

Tags: polar-coordinates, curves

[Problem description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZR2t.jpg)

Please help me in part i of the question. I am just confused about the range of the curve which does not include $2\pi$. Does this mean that the curve should not touch the initial line the second time? It touches the initial line the first time when $\theta=0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Taha You are right. In your sketch, you can draw the line to the x-axis, but put a white circle at the end to show that the point does not exist there.

Comment: @TobyMak thanks!